# Need help to convert code from pure JavaScript to jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a code on pure JavaScript.
How it be on jQuery?
And how to make it much shorter?

Trying to do it by myself but have some problems with `getElementsByTagName`.

```
function searchFunction() {
   var input, filter, ul, li, a, i, txtValue;
   input = document.getElementById("searchinput");
   filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
   ul = document.getElementById("itemlist");
   li = ul.getElementsByTagName('li');
   if (filter.length < 2) { 
      $("body").addClass("sigf");
   } else {
      $("body").removeClass("sigf");
   } 
   for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
      a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("div")[0];
      txtValue = a.textContent || a.innerText;
      if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
         li[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
         li[i].style.display = "none";
      }
   }
}
```

I’ve stopped here:

```
function searchFunction() {
   var input, filter, ul, li, a, i, txtValue;
   input = $("#searchinput")[0];
   filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
   ul = $("#itemlist")[0];
   li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
   if (filter.length < 2) { 
      $("body").addClass("sigf");
   } else {
      $("body").removeClass("sigf");
   } 
   for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
      a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("div")[0];
      txtValue = a.textContent || a.innerText;
      if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
         li[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
         li[i].style.display = "none";
      }
   }
}
```

When I’m trying to replace `li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");` with `li = ul.$("li");` everything stop working.

Comment: Which problem are you experiencing? What’s the expected output and what are you seeing instead?

Comment: Why the need to use jQuery? Just because the code may be shorter leveraging the capabilities of jQuery, it will likely be slower.

Comment: Hi! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!) and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) jQuery is a **library**, not a language. What you're trying to do is convert JavaScript code using the DOM directly to JavaScript code using jQuery. Your best bet here is to do your research (https://api.jquery.com), [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: Ok. I’ve written where I’m get stuck.

Comment: use this instead "li = $("#itemlist li");"

Answer (score 1):

You have some mistakes :

- `input = $("#searchinput")[0]` and `ul = $("#itemlist")[0]`: no nees for  `[0]` as you're getting the elements by their `ID`s so you'll have `only one` element in the returned `jQuery` objects.
- `li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li")`: `ul` is a `jQuery` object and it doesn't have a method called `getElementsByTagName`, use `li = ul.find("li")` instead.
- `for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++)`: not really wrong but if you want to use `jQuery` try to benefit from all of its power as it does provide a `each` method that calls a callback function for every element in a `jQuery` object, you may use `li.each(function(index, element) {...}` instead.
- `a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("div")[0]`: this could be divided into three points

  - as here we're in a loop using the `each` method (no *explicit* `for` loop nor an `i` variable) we can't fetch an element by an index as we could use `a = element.` (remember the arguments sent to the callback in the point above) or simply `a = $(this).` and `jQuery` will give you the correct element in the set.
  - as of `a`, now, is a `jQuery` object, it doesn't have a method called `getElementsByTagName`, use the `find` method instead like so `a = $(this).find("div")`.
  - now we the `div`s (returned by the `find` method which returns a `jQuery` object) we can get the first element by calling `get(0)` instead of `[0]`. The final expression becomes `a = $(this).find("div").get(0)`
- `txtValue = a.textContent || a.innerText`: no need for that checking (anyway `jQuery` doesn't have a `textContent` nor `innerText` attribute) let `jQuery` do it for you using the `text` method like so `txtValue = a.text()`.
- `li[i].style.display`: as we already said that `li[i]` is incorrect and assuming that it became `$(this)`, considering that the expression is `$(this).style.display` which is incorrect as `jQuery` doesn't have an attribute called `style` (nor `display` is an attribute in the `style` as the last is undefined already) this should be `$(this).css(rule, value)` or `$(this).css(CSSRulesObject)` where `CSSObject` is a key/value pairs object that defines `CSS` rules.

Anyway, hope I came along the most of the mistakes and here's an updated version (from pure `JavaScript` to `jQuery`) of the code provided in the question

```
function searchFunction() {
  var input = = $("#searchinput"),
    filter = input.val().toUpperCase(),
    ul = $("#itemlist"),
    li = ul.find('li'),
    a, txtValue;
  if (filter.length < 2) {
    $("body").addClass("sigf");
  } else {
    $("body").removeClass("sigf");
  }
  a = $(this).find("div").get(0);
  txtValue = a.text();
  if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
    $(this).css('display', "");
  } else {
    $(this).css('display', "none");
  }
}
```

> As I don't have the required markup for this code to work properly, I didn't manage to test the above portion of code, sorry for any issues that may appear.
>
> Also, I didn't try to correct any thing that relates to the way your function should work as I don't really know what you're aiming to do.

Answer (score 0):

I've converted your code to jQuery. Few words about methods used:

1. I used [toggleClass()](https://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) method to toggle `sigf` class based on the filter length.
2. I used [each()](https://api.jquery.com/each/#each-function) method to iterate over all ul's li
3. I used [css()](https://api.jquery.com/css/) method to assign `disaplay` property based on your requirements

Now your functions looks:

```
function searchFunction() {

  $("body").toggleClass('sigf', $("#searchinput").val().toUpperCase().length < 2);

  $("#itemlist").find('li').each(function() {
    var a = $(this).find('div');
    var txtValue = a.text();
    $(this).css('display', function() {
      return txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1 ? '' : 'none';
    });
  });
}
```

I would advise your to read about [jquery-selectors](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/). This article should answer why your code is not working. If not, I'll try to explain it in details.